# Delete ACM certificate after CloudFront was deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

I had a CloudFront distribution with a custom ACM certificate associated with it. The CloudFront was deleted, but I cannot delete the certificate, it says it’s still in use by that CloudFront, that no longer exist. Any idea what is happening and how do I delete the certificate?

Using either terraform or AWS console if this matters.

Comment: Usually waiting a bit helps. When did you delete your CF distro?

Comment: Last attempt to delete certificate was made about 5 hour after CF was deleted. I had similar issue with lambda@edge for that CF, in that case waiting did help, but I had to wait 30-40 min before I could delete it.

Comment: When you run [aws acm describe-certificate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/acm/describe-certificate.html) does it show any extra info?

Comment: It returns this huge JSON with tons of info, including "inUseBy" pointing to that CF

Comment: Did you ever find this out? I've been waiting days...

Comment: For me it took 15-30 minutes _after_ cloudfront said it was deleted for the ACM cert to say "not is use"